# PDF merge using iText throws OOM error

Tags: pdf, merge, out-of-memory, itext

I am trying to merge 10 PDF files (~ 1000 pages each) into a single files using the iText APIs. Below is the code for merging. It's breaking with OOM error just after 8 or 9 files. How can I maximize this to 100 files, since that is my desired result.

```
public class IText {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException{

    String ifs2 = "C:\\Downloads\\02.pdf";
    String result = "C:\\Merge\\final.pdf";
    String[] stArray = new String[10]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        stArray[i]=ifs2;
    }

    mergeFiles(stArray,result, false);

}

public static void mergeFiles(String[] files, String result, boolean smart) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy;
        if (smart)
            copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(result));
        else
            copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(result));
        document.open();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            reader.close();
        }
        document.close();
    }
```

UPDATE: I tried the below method inside my for loop. Still getting the error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            RandomAccessSourceFactory rasf = new RandomAccessSourceFactory();
            RandomAccessSource ras = rasf.createBestSource(files[i]);
            RandomAccessFileOrArray raf = new   RandomAccessFileOrArray(ras);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(raf, null);
            copy.addDocument(reader);
            raf.close();
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

Comment: How much memory does your java vm have allocated? How big are the source pdfs (in bytes, not pages)?

Comment: I have 2gig allocated heap space. also the files are roughly 7MB

Comment: Could you share a sample file to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://saibababojja.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/pro-linq-in-c-2010.pdf

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue with your sample file. 725 MB sufficed for the program to run without problem, at 700 MB I got an OutOfMemory, too. That your tests even fail for 2 GB is quite a surprise. What kind of JRE do you use? I use an Oracle JVM 8.

Comment: JRE 6. Its throwing the error at reader and so I thought closing the reader inside the for loop, would resolve it, but no use.

Comment: JRE 6, ok, heap management improved much since then. I'm afraid even the mere 725 MB my setup requires help you much as you want to apply your code to ten times as many files. Probably iText needs a really dumb copier with a small memory footprint...

Comment: Jre 6 is the constraint. I believe that's what I have to work with. I was trying different ways to read the files or create Pdfreader to improve the performance. But no luck so far.